# Exporting large results of a MySQL and Oracle Query

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am testing data migration for which I have created 2 SQL scripts , one for Oracle server and 1 for MySQL. My idea is to export their results to a .txt files and then compare it using unix DIFF.
It works perfectly for small files but for large files the clients for Oracle and MySQL do not support such huge file to be exported.

One way is to break query results and then compare but it is extremity time consuming.In my opinion if I could break the resultset in batches using some program, it could be possibel.

Please suggest me a easy method to do that.
Thanks
Ajay

Comment: Which "clients" are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Run the same query on both databases (sort the data in the same way). Compere it line by line before writing it to a file.

```
Step 1a: Select data from Oracle
Step 1b: Select data from MySQL
Step 2:  Compare results row against row.
Step 3a: Write to file 1
Step 3b: Write to file 2
```

How to compare? Concatenate columns. example from Oracle: col1||','||col2||','||col3. Do the same in MySQL. At this point you are able to compare row against row not just string against string.

The question is with which tool? The answer: Pentaho Data Integration. The best open source ETL tool.

Download: http://community.pentaho.com/

How to use it: http://pldwh.blogspot.co.uk/

If you know any OOP language. You can write it yourself. As long you will sort the data and concatenate columns you are good to go.